# std::result_of on std::bind does not compile on clang++ 3.4

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, clang++, result-of

The following code compiles using g++-4.8 but it doesn't when using clang 3.4.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

struct A {
    template <typename Continuation>
    bool operator()(
            //const  Continuation & continuation
            Continuation continuation
        ) const {
        return true;
    }
};

bool  f(A)  {
    return true;
}

auto g(A a) ->
typename  std::result_of<A(
    decltype(std::bind(f, a)))>::type
{
    auto continuation = std::bind(f, a);

    return a(continuation);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    A a;
    g(a);
}
```

g++-4.8 -std=c++0x test.cpp # OK

clang++ -std=c++0x test.cpp

```
test.cpp:22:38: error: no type named 'type' in 'std::result_of<A (std::_Bind<bool (*(A))(A)>)>'
    decltype(std::bind(f, a)))>::type
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
1 error generated.
```

When you uncomment the commented line and comment the following one, the code compiles on both clang ang g++.

Comment: It seems like std::bind's result is not copyable when compiled with clang as the following correction to the code makes it compile fine with both g++ and clang++ to me:
typename std::result_of<A(
    decltype(std::move(std::bind(f, a))))>::type

Comment: Well my assupmtion about it to be non-copyable has been discarded by a simple test.
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_copy_constructible<decltype(std::bind(f, std::declval<A>()))>::value << std::endl; // outputs "true" with both GCC and Clang

Comment: @user2590425 You don't copy the `bind` object in the body of `g`. You only initialize an `auto` variable, which most probably doesn't copy. The error does not make sense to me, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind): "The object is movable if f and all args are movable, and is copyable otherwise." Both versions compile fine in GCC 4.8.1 and clang 3.3 for me.

Answer (score 1):

result_of was prior to decltype, you should simplify the syntax like this :

```
auto g(A a) -> decltype( std::declval<A>()( std::bind(f, a) ) )
```

Comment: That works fine. Still, my version should work as well. Also, the result_of is sometimes more useful than decltype, because you do not have to type declvals.